# ajax jquery call doesnt work for me

Tags: php, jquery, json

UPDATE:

I need to get the jason.. The click event doesnt work why..

**update:**

```
               <script>

$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#RefreshButton").click(function(){
                       $.ajax({
                           url: "/test2/ajax.php",
                           type: "GET",
                           dataType: "json",
                           success: function(data)
                           {
                               alert("This is my data: "+data);
                               $(".article").remove();
                               $.each(data, function(key, value){
                                   $('articleColumn').append( '<p class="article"><font size="5"><b>'+value[0]+'</b></font><br/>'
                                       +value[1]+' <a href="#" class="readMore">Read more...</a></p>');
                               });
                           },
                           error: function( error )
                           {
                               alert(JSON.stringify(error));

                           }
                       });

                   });
               });
   </script>
```

The ajax call works..but not when it is in the click event handler..why?!?

I think the solution to the problem lies in the html:

```
   <a href="" id="RefreshButton" >Refresh</a>
```

may be it refreshes the page and then send the response. I think it is the problem in the way the event propogates ..hmm

Comment: your page should be in local server exemple `http://localhost/mypage.html`

Comment: probably not gonna change much, but have you tried setting the `contentType`?

Comment: What do you see with `firebug`?

Comment: Can you post the url of the page that contains this js?

Comment: use `dataType` instead of `datatype`

Comment: can you paste the output of:  curl http://localhost/test2/ajax.php

Comment: I have this:      header("Content-Type: application/json", true); in my ajax.php. Everything is updated above!!!

Comment: Are you saying the `error` block triggers instead of the `success` one?

Comment: Perhaps it is a cross-domain problem, what happens if you use just `url: "/test2/ajax.php",` in the second line?

Comment: I get an error, jeroen. Forever_Zombie..that didnt help. my answer update...YEah, Marc,, it goes to the error function each time

Comment: I think I got why I have the problem..it is because of that event in my link. If I dont use the click event and onload instead it works

Answer (score 0):

Generally when making an ajax call using jQuery I use the short hand version of POST and GET methods. So in your case I would do something like this

```
$.get("ajax.php", function(data){
  alert(data); //just to make sure it works
}, "json");
```

Be sure to send the response back from ajax.php as json using json_encode(array("key"=>"value","key"=>"value")); ?>)

Also since ajax cannot go across domains you don't have to specify http://localhost/ajax.php, rather you can just specify it as the relative path to where you are calling the jquery function from.

Comment: i dont want to use get. I want to use json. see update. I think it might be in the way events propogate

Comment: yup..I solved my own problem..I had to return false; on the click event handler.. good 2 hours went on that bug